# Retrieve Google Contact create date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I need to retrieve the creation date of a Google Contact.

I know that I can use [getLastUpdated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#getlastupdated) to get the last modified date, but I need the create date.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts). From the response body you will be able to get the created date. Also [this post from stackexchage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39164/finding-time-when-google-contact-got-created) suggested to use [API Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to visually walk through making a request to get the data you want from Google Contacts API.

> This information is not traditionally exposed through the Google
>   Contacts online interface. However! You can get access to "created"
>   and "updates" dates and times using the Google Contacts API.
>
> If you're not a developer, you can use the [API Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to visually
>   walk you through making a request to the Google Contacts API to get
>   the data you want.